# Variable not reactive in composable when passed a a computedRef in parent component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

My issue can be reproduced [here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Explanation :
I have multiple layers of components :
App.vue -> ChildComp.vue -> GrandChildComp.vue

I am trying to pass an object and a primitive down the hierarchy and to keep it reactivity. Testing reactivity with the button to toggle the value of the boolean primitive.

Reactivity is well kept inside components but things get diffrent when I pass it to a composable.
When passing my test primitive to the composable in ChildComp.vue using toRef reactivity works, but when I pass my test primitive to the composable created this time inside GrandChildComp.vue reactivity is broken.

I know the diffrence is that primitive is passed as a prop to GrandChildComp.vue wrapped in a computedRef `<GrandChildComp :mix="computedRef"/>` but I don't understand why I had to pass to the composable a computedRef to keep reactivity. When I pass primitive wrapped in a reactive object to GrandChildComp.vue `<GrandChildComp :mix="props"/>` reactivity is kept this time only with a toRef.

Sorry if my explanation is not clear, I have tried to add comment inside the example to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this code:

```
const ref = toRef(props.mix, "primitive")
useComposable("GrandChildComp ref", ref)
```

If the parent passes a completely new `mix` value, the ref will point to an outdated value. This statement is only reactive on the `props.mix` value initially passed.

As opposed to here:

```
const cref = computed(() => props.mix.primitive)
useComposable("GrandChildComp cref", cref)
```

The statement is reactive on `props` itself.

I think going with the computed ref is your best bet.

By the way, if you want to pass down a value to a descendant, you can use `inject` and `provide` instead.

Comment: I understand. But why a code like const ref0 = toRef(props, "mix") const ref = toRef(ref0, "primitive") const ref = toRef(ref0, "primitive") does not work ?

Comment: Because `ref0` is not a reactive object, it's a `Ref`. `toRef(ref0, "primitive")` will not work, because it's `ref0.value.primitive` not `ref0.primitive`

Answer (score 0):

You also doing it too complex. Here is the simplified working [SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Use [`toRefs()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#torefs)

```
const { primitive, object} = toRefs(props);
useComposable("ChildComp primitive", primitive);
const mix = reactive({ primitive, object});
```

and

```
const props = defineProps<Props>();
const { primitive, object } = toRefs( props.mix );
useComposable("GrandChildComp primitive", primitive)
```

or as `computed()`

```
const { primitive, object} = toRefs(props);
useComposable("ChildComp primitive", primitive);
const mix = computed(() => {
  return { primitive, object }
})
```

Comment: I need mix to be a computedRef in ChildComp this maybe too complex in this example but this example was only a simplification of my real code with a computedRef that's why I used it here